Understanding dynamics in Aghion-Howitt (1992) model (aka Schumpeterian growth)
The seminal Aghion-Howitt (1992) paper is about endogenous growth due to innovations (i.e. new intermediate products that improve the overall quality of output).
There is an equilibrium of the base model presented on page 332. It reflects intersection of two equations that have been derived with time dynamics in mind (forward-looking logic). Usually they are shown in a bit simplifying mathematical form as a system of two equations (that can roughly be understood as supply and demand for research staff, $n$, that could bring innovations with some probability $\lambda$). Here $\omega$ stands for wages of skilled labor. Notice time indexes order.
$$
\omega_t = \lambda \frac{\gamma \tilde{\pi}(\omega_{t+1})}{r + \lambda n_{t+1}}
$$
$$
L = n_t + \tilde{x}_t(\omega_t)
$$
Symbols with tilde, like $\tilde{\pi}$, reflect some function. From the above equations one (perhaps) can derive a dynamic motion for $n$ of some form $n_t = \psi(n_{t+1})$. Notice the dependence direction.
The original picture is a help to readers' account:

I'm having hard time to understand, why do they claim $n_0 = \psi (n_1)$, while on the picture the arrow and the description goes in normal direction, i.e. $n_0 \rightarrow n_1$ and so on to $\hat{n}$.
Some explanations and tips will be welcome. I would like to make a computer simulation, thus clear understanding of all formulas is important.
